# Manutenção em código para upload de imagens com tamanho original

Tags: php, html5

Estou fazendo manutenção em um código que utiliza a função abaixo para fazer uploads e redimensionar a imagem:

```
    function uploadArquivo($file, $dir_file, $prefixo_nome, $thumb = false, $dir_thumb = array(), $sizes = array()) {

  $nome_imagem = $file['name'];
  preg_match('/\.(gif|png|jpg|jpeg|pdf|doc|docx|rtf|txt|xls|xlsx|ppt|pptx|cdr|mp3|wma|aac|ogg|ac3|wav|mp4|avi|rmvb|mkv|bmp|zip|rar|7z){1}$/i', $nome_imagem, $ext);
  $ext = strtolower($ext[1]);
  $nome_imagem_formatado = $prefixo_nome . "_" . date('YmdHis') . str_replace(".", "", substr((string)microtime(), 1, 8)) . "." . $ext;
  $caminho = $dir_file . $nome_imagem_formatado;
  move_uploaded_file($file['tmp_name'], $caminho);

  if ($thumb) {
    for($i = 0; $i < count($dir_thumb); $i++) {
      $caminho_thumb = $dir_file . $dir_thumb[$i] . $nome_imagem_formatado;
      $imagem_file = CroppedThumbnail($caminho, $sizes[$i][0], $sizes[$i][1], $ext);
      imagejpeg($imagem_file, $caminho_thumb, 100);
    }
    // apaga original depois de recortar tudo o que precisa
    deleteArquivo($caminho);
  }
```

Abaixo, redimensionando a imagem para 1550 x 750px:

```
$this->setUrlImagem(uploadArquivo($_FILES["imagem"], 'uploads/', 'produto', true, array('produtos/'), array(array(1550,750))));
```

Preciso fazer o seguinte:

- Upload da imagem com tamanho original e mover para pasta
  "upload/produtos/originais";
- redimensionar para altura 320px e altura    proporcional à original e
  mover para a pasta "upload/produtos"